# Good practice in calling accessor methods?

Tags: java

Please forgive me if this question is stupid...I am a newbie when it comes to programming. One thing that I am confused is whether or not I should instantiate a new variable everytime I call a method which gets some value or keep a local copy and update that.

To illustrate, suppose I have a robot navigating a maze. The robot driver operates the robot and must get the robot's coordinates to perform some action such as sensing obstacles.

```
public class RoboDriver {
   public void senseObstacle() {
     int[] position = robot.getPosition();
     ...
   }
}

public class RoboDriver {
   int[] robotPositionCopy;
   public void senseObstacle() {
     this.robotPositionCopy = robot.getPosition();
     ...
   }
}
```

The position coordinates are always up to date in the robot object. So if I want to get the updated position, which of these two examples is better and why? Or does it not make much of a difference?

Comment: It depends on how/when you need to use the information.

Comment: @DaveNewton In this case, I only need the updated coordinates when RoboDriver is trying to sense something. So everytime sense is called, it needs the updated coordinates.

Comment: You could use both. However, the 2nd approach will keep the array object in memory typically longer than a local variable.

Comment: @Mohammad So performance wise, the 1st approach is slightly better?

Comment: In the second example, if you save `robotPositionCopy`, are you planning on using it in a future method without calling `getPosition()` again?

Comment: @Renren29 yes and it follows the OOP encapsulation principle.

Comment: @ajb No, I do not plan to use robotPositionCopy without updating it first.

Comment: @Renren29 Then there's probably no reason to save it in a `RoboDriver` instance variable (as opposed to a local variable, as in the first example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One does not *instantiate* a local variable and your saying that makes me think you may be considering this as coming at a cost. Local variables are absolutely free: they are just names given to memory locations which will exist *anyway* on the method's stack frame.

As opposed to that, your second example declares an *instance* variable, and that one does come at a cost: each instance of your class will have to reserve memory on the heap for it, even though you use it only while executing the method.

So, I think the advice is unanymous: do not declare instance variables unless you need them to hold long-lived object state.